# append arbitrary data to IIS W3C logs?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to append my own column to the IIS W3C request logs is this possible?

I want IIS to add a custom column and value to each log line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding, It is not possible to add a new line as the only available fields are [W3C fields](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754702(v=ws.10).aspx) in your log format( is chosen as W3C in IIS settings). You can overwrite a particular field coming in W3C log but you have to write a custom Module to do that and this [article](http://joe-pruitt.sys-con.com/node/1230679/mobile) has sample code to do that

> Howewer you can install [AdvancedLogging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging) module for IIS and it
>   allows a [comprehensive list of custom fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging#custom)

Answer (score 0):

You can append custom log data to the IIS log.  However it is appended to UriQuery column.

Append via a call to [Response.AppendToLog(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendtolog.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[W3C.zip related files](http://xlsure.com/W3C/)
You could import the W3C format, scrubbing out the headers, then add your own.
Like this for example:

```
Step 1:
 get the log u_ex181121.log [get rid of the first 3 header rows  leaving the 4th but taking out just this '#Fields: ']
 so your header should look like this:
 date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken

Step 2:
 Remove any more headers that may appear in the log file throughout the life of the log file.

Step 3:
 Import Parse the file (For example manually with EXCEL or some other ETL process delimiting by space   
  See W3C.zip for related files:
  u_ex181121.log = the log file generated by IIS
  u_ex181121.log.xls = the imported version of u_ex181121.log
  _ULog_StatusLU.xls = the Status Code Lookup 
  2018.11.21_Query_Results.xls = the results from the W3C_LOG.sql query
  W3C_LOG.sql = the query


            --Query Logs
            SELECT
                tRet.[date]
                , tRet.[date-time]
                , tRet.[date-time-mst]
                , tRet.[s-ip]
                , tRet.[cs-method]
                , tRet.[cs-uri-stem]
                , tRet.[cs-uri-query]
                , tRet.[s-port]
                , tRet.[cs-username]
                , tRet.[c-ip]
                , tRet.[cs(User-Agent)]
                , tRet.[sc-status]
                , tRet.[sc-substatus]
                , tRet.[sc-win32-status]
                , tRet.[time-taken] 
                , tRet.[time-taken-seconds]  
                , tRet.[time-taken-minutes]
                , tRet.[sc-status-Description]
                , tRet.[sc-status-Notes] 
            From
            (
                SELECT
                    Cast(l.[date] As Date) [date]
                    , Cast(Replace(Cast(l.[date] As varchar(20)), ' 00:00:00.', '') + Cast(Replace(Replace(Cast(l.[time] as varchar(20)), '1899-12-31', ''), '.', '') as varchar(20)) As DateTime) As [date-time]
                    , DateAdd('n', (-60*7), (Cast(Replace(Cast(l.[date] As varchar(20)), ' 00:00:00.', '') + Cast(Replace(Replace(Cast(l.[time] as varchar(20)), '1899-12-31', ''), '.', '') as varchar(20)) As DateTime))) As [date-time-mst]
                    , l.[s-ip]
                    , l.[cs-method]
                    , l.[cs-uri-stem]
                    , l.[cs-uri-query]
                    , l.[s-port]
                    , l.[cs-username]
                    , l.[c-ip]
                    , l.[cs(User-Agent)]
                    , l.[sc-status]
                    , l.[sc-substatus]
                    , l.[sc-win32-status]
                    , l.[time-taken] 
                    , ROUND((l.[time-taken] * .001), 2) As [time-taken-seconds]
                    , ROUND((l.[time-taken] * 1.66667e-5), 4) As [time-taken-minutes]
                    , lu.[sc-status-Description]
                    , lu.[sc-status-Notes] 
                FROM
                    [u_ex181121.log].[u_ex181121] l
                    Left Outer Join [_ULog_StatusLU].[StatusLU] lu on l.[sc-status] = lu.[sc-status]
            ) tRet
            Order By
            tRet.[date-time-mst] DESC[enter link description here][1]
```